# Styled-components, SVG not animating

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I use styled-components alongside React and I have such component:

```
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components'
import { ReactComponent as SpinnerIcon } from './spinner.svg'

const rotate = keyframes`
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
`

const Spinner = styled(SpinnerIcon)`
    margin-top: 50px;
    animation: ${rotate} 2s ease-in infinite;
`

export default Spinner
```

When I use this component like this:

```
<Spinner width='50px' height='50px' />
```

I see this component but it's not animating. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  const Spinner = styled.img.attrs({
      src: SpinnerIcon,
    })`
        margin-top: 50px;
        animation: ${rotate} 2s ease-in infinite;
```

if this doesn't work for you please share your svg file too. Also you probably need use **linear**  function instead of **ease-in**
        `

Comment: This kinda works. But I get some errors. src attribure has to be a string fo a cannot pass SpinnerIcon, but when I give it './spinner.svg', I see an animation but with no icon, only with this not found thing.

Comment: use default  import:    import  ReactComponent as SpinnerIcon  from './spinner.svg'

Comment: When I import like this `import { ReactComponent as SpinnerIcon } from './spinner.svg'` I get this long error: `Argument of type '{ src: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> & { title?: string | undefined; }>; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Attrs<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>, HTMLImageElement>, "slot" | ... 264 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; }, Partial<...> & { ...; }, any>`

Comment: Also this: `ype 'FunctionComponent<SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> & { title?: string | undefined; }>' is not assignable to type 'string'`

Comment: You were right, I just have to import it like this: `import SpinnerIcon from './spinner.svg'`